# Clarification on I/Q Mixer output

Tags: rf, radio, microwave, receiver, mixer

I'm working on RF Receiver, it is required to use I/Q Mixer for IF downconversion. Specification as follows below

```
LO/RF Frequency: 0.5-1 GHz
IF Frequency Range: DC-1000 MHZ
```

What will happen if I drive RF and LO at the same frequency, for example, RF: 500 MHz, IF: 500 MHz

Can I expect the DC output for I/Q? Or let me know what output can I expect?

Comment: You'll find output at both 0 Hz and 2*F = 1 GHz. For the DC case, search "homodyne" or "direct conversion" receivers. They have their own unique problems...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there power level will split in I and Q outputs? As datasheet it was mentioned 7.5 dB conversion loss which means total loss will be 7.5 dB when combined it I&Q signals together. can you please clarify me ?

Comment: No I can't, sorry.